# How to update SerialNumber column of a database table as per Row Number function in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to update serialnumber column with row Number() where serialnumber column is set with identity. Below is the code I am using but it is giving Identity Error (Cannot update identity column 'SNO'):

```
update tableSalesQuotation
set
SNO=SubQuery.SNO
from
(SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY SNO) as SNO
FROM tableSalesQuotation
) SubQuery
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove gaps in an identity column. Don't try to do this. Life is so much easier if you treat identity columns as opaque blobs that just happen to fit in numeric columns. You shouldn't *care* what the actual numeric values are.

Comment: Damien, Could you please elaborate by giving an example. Thanks.

Comment: I have a table where some entries may be deleted. Earlier S.No generated was 1,2,3,4,5 now row no 2,4, deleted then in table S.No should be like 1,2,3 instead of 1,3,5. Pls help.Thanks

Comment: And that's what I'm saying you should seek to avoid even *trying* to do. Accept that there will be gaps and just use the values that you're given and you'll have a much easier life. If you want to *display* continuous numbers, use a *view* that performs the `ROW_NUMBER()` for you during `SELECT`, but leave the actual numbers in the table alone.